# Locking transactions (SQL Server + EF5)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I am trying to debug a performance issue in an ASP.NET application using .NET 4.5, EF5 (with a 2nd level cache and lazy loaded navigation properties) and SQL Server 2014. We are experiencing a number of wait locks in the SQL server. When I look at the locking transactions, they contain a very quick UPDATE, and then a very large SELECT. The UPDATE is ostensibly a necessary one, but I am confused as to why the SELECT is being run in the same transaction (and why anything is being selected at all). The fundamental issue is that the table referenced in the UPDATE statement is locked for the duration of the SELECT statement.

We use repository pattern for getting data from the db, and DbContext.SaveChanges() for committing changes. I cannot figure out how it is possible that EF produces a transaction where there is both a write and a read, and I am not getting relevant results when I try to search Google.

We have a number of interfaces into the system, and a couple of console applications working on the database as well, but they all go through the same setup/versions of .NET and EF.

I figure that it must be through SaveChanges, since this is (AFAIK) the only time that things are written to the database.

Does anyone here have a hint as to how these locking transactions might be produced?

Comment: Select after update is expected in SaveChanges.  But the Updates caused by SaveChanges() should acquire sufficient locks to allow the subsequent SELECT's to execute without blocking. So you need to diagnose the SELECT's to figure out why they are long-running. For instance, if you were missing a primary key index, the SELECT might require a scan.

Answer (score 0):

> The fundamental issue is that the table referenced in the UPDATE
>   statement is locked for the duration of the SELECT statement.

The answer is in your question:

> the SELECT is being run in the same transaction

`X` lock is always held until the end of the `transaction`, i.e. until it commits or rolls back. So if after your quick `update` there is a long `select`, all that `update` locked in your table remains locked until your `select` ends.

You can separate your `update` and `select` if your business rules permit, you can add an appropriate `index` on the updated table to lock only some rows and not the whole table, or you can optimize your `select` to execute faster.

Comment: I realize that the reason for the lock is that the statements are grouped in a transaction, and that separating them would solve the issue. The problem is that I don't know why or how they are grouped in the first place. Using repository pattern and SaveChanges I have no idea how it is possible for EF to produce a transaction with a read and a write in the samme transaction, and so, I am having a hard time locating the code that produces the issue.

Comment: I don't know how to help you with EF, but you still can create an index in order to reduce locking when you update the table. I suspect you have a heap, otherwise the whole table should not be locked

Comment: The SaveChanges() call will not only insert/update/delete all entities referenced in the contexts ChangeTracker, but Select all entries after the call committed to ensure everything is updated correctly (based on the defined Concurrency Tokens). All of this happens within the ambient Transaction used in the DbConnection, or, if none exists, in a separate transaction EF creates to encapsulate the SaveChanges() call.